# Is there an extended function library for SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, function

Is there an extended function library for sqlite?

I am trying out sqlite and realized that a lot of the functions I could expect to take for granted in other sql databases don't exist in it, although it appears they can be added to it.

Are there some ready made libraries like that for it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Extension functions for SQLite in C for free**
http://old.nabble.com/Extension-functions-for-SQLite-in-C-for-free-td8833684.html

FTS3 is an SQLite virtual table module that allows users to perform full-text searches on a set of documents. 
http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html

Comment: Not that I know of.  The code for SQLite is designed to be as portable as possible, so that people can make their own builds, including any external libraries.  I suppose it also relieves the author of SQLite from creating builds for every possible platform (it is just one guy, AFAIK).